# How can I resend the invitation to an event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

It seems some of the people I've invited to my event have not received an email invitation to take part on the event. How do I resend the invitation to the people who have not yet responded?

I tried the *Email guests* functionality, but they only received the information about the event, not an actual invitation. So there's no way for them to accept it and copy it to their calendars.

Comment: The way I've done it is to remove the person as a guest and then re-add them.

Comment: I'd have thought there'd be a better way...

Answer (score 5):

The best way I've found to do this is:

1. Remove guests from the event and save (Do not send the notification)
2. Add guests again and Save (Send event invite).

Comment: How would you do this if the person is part of a group?

Answer (score 1):

If the person you try to invite is using Google Calendar, you can obtain a link to to add the event to their Google Calendar. The link is shown when you click on "publish event" link (at the bottom of the calendar invite detail page).

Comment: I wouldn't say this really solves the problem, it may help though and perhaps it's the best google has to offer at this time, so I give you +1 for the effort.